# Child theme not loading parent theme styles | SnowdogApps blank-sass

Tags: magento2, theme, sass

**SOLVED** (Answer below)

I had to add this to themes.json that took styles.scss and print.scss from Snowdog/blank and compiled it to my Training/default:

```
"default-blank": {
    "src": "vendor/snowdog/theme-blank-sass",
    "dest": "pub/static/frontend/Training/default",
    "locale": ["en_US"],
    "localeOverwrites": true,
    "stylesDir": "styles"
}
```

And then run `sudo gulp styles --theme default-blank`

---

All pages have no styling when I change my Magento 2 theme to my own theme that has SnowdogApps blank-sass as the parent theme.

There are a few errors in console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://edu.dev/pub/static/frontend/Training/default/en_US/css/print.css 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://edu.dev/pub/static/frontend/Training/default/en_US/css/print.css

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://edu.dev/pub/static/frontend/Training/default/en_US/css/styles.css 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://edu.dev/pub/static/frontend/Training/default/en_US/css/print.css
```

My theme in themes.json:

```
  "default": {
    "src": "app/design/frontend/Training/default",
    "dest": "pub/static/frontend/Training/default",
    "locale": ["en_US"],
    "localeOverwrites": true,
    "parent": "blank",
    "stylesDir": "web/css/source"
  }
```

Am I missing something in theme structure?

```
Training/default
|-Magento_Cms
|    |-web 
|         |-css
|              |-source
|                      |-_extend.scss
|-media
|      |-preview.jpg
|-web
|    |-css
|    |    |-source
|    |            |-_variables.scss
|    |            |-_extend.scss
|    |-images
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add this to themes.json that took styles.scss and print.scss from Snowdog/blank and compiled it to my Training/default:

```
"default-blank": {
    "src": "vendor/snowdog/theme-blank-sass",
    "dest": "pub/static/frontend/Training/default",
    "locale": ["en_US"],
    "localeOverwrites": true,
    "stylesDir": "styles"
}
```

And then run `sudo gulp styles --theme default-blank`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the full name of the parent theme (vendor/theme) in your config file.

`Snowdog/blank` for the Snowdog Sass theme or `Magento/blank` for the original Magento theme

Comment: Snowdog/blank is defined as "blank" in the themes.json also. I had named it Snowdog/blank in `"parent": "blank",`  before, but when I tried to compile sass files it said that parent theme can't be found, then I changed it to blank and it compiled successfully.